# angular2 material and date - how to get the currently selected date

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Dudes of angular2 material apparently did not want to show how to get the currently selected date...selectedChanged returns the last date.

```
 <md-input-container>
                    <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [(ngModel)]="wtf">
                    <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker"></button>
            </md-input-container>
            <md-datepicker #picker [startAt]="startDate" (selectedChanged)="duder()"></md-datepicker>



duder(){
      console.log('duder',this.startDate,this.wtf)
      console.log('duder--r',moment(this.wtf).format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
  }
```

I mean wow..I make a change..and what I get is the last date..not the current date that I selected.

If I change the date..how do I get the current date from my duder() function?

Comment: I tried your code. I am getting the currently selected date :S

https://plnkr.co/edit/05yGj6Zbt4OYIfD3DcON?p=preview

Comment: that is very odd...in the console in chrome...what is printed is the previous date.  But I did verify that the current selected date if using the template {{wtf}}.  This can be damaging if e.g. the dude func has to make a rest request.

Comment: So if I submit as a separate event all is well..I just cant get the current date from the selectedChagne function

Answer (score 2):

So the trick is anytime you deal with `@Output` in angular, pass in the `$event` to emit the new value to the function. Just add that to your `duder()` and you will be set.

`(selectedChanged)="duder($event)"`

```
duder(date){
    console.log('duder', date);
    this.wtf = date;
}
```

I have updated the [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/05yGj6Zbt4OYIfD3DcON?p=preview)